# Permit a user to create new accounts

Tags: users

I am looking for a way to allow one type of users to create a second type of users.

Can anyone advise me on how to do this?

I am using the profile module but creating a profile does not create a corresponding user who owns the profile.

Comment: By "type of users" do you mean users with a specific role? Are you interested only to a module, or are you interested also to code you can write to reach that purpose?

Comment: Yes, I meant users with specific roles and I would prefer a module solution, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Role Delegation](http://drupal.org/project/role_delegation) module.

> This module allows site administrators to grant some roles the
>   authority to assign selected roles to users, without them needing the
>   administer permissions permission.
>
> For each role, Role Delegation provides a new assign ROLE role
>   permission to allow the assignment of that role.
>
> The module also adds an assign all roles permission. Enabling this
>   permission for a role is a convenient way to allow the assignment of
>   any other role without having to check all the assign ROLE role
>   permissions in the Permissions page.
>
> If an administrator has the administer users permission, a role
>   assignment widget gets displayed in the account creation or editing
>   form, and bulk add/remove role operations become available on the user
>   administration page. Otherwise, if s/he has at least the access user
>   profiles permission, the module adds its own Roles tab to the user
>   profile so that roles can be assigned.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, go to `admin/people/permissions` and way down at the bottom under 'Users,' there is an option for 'Administer users.' Pretty sure it's similar in D6. The pattern would be to create a new group, with a name like 'Officer' and give officers this power.

The super ultra mega downside to this is that any user with this power can delete user 1. So don't do it. :-) I suggest an invitation system instead: http://drupal.org/project/invite.

Comment: Does the Invite module allow to create users with a specific role, where the role is decided from who sends the invite, or where the role is decided upon the role of who sends the invite?

Comment: Not sure about a new role for invited people.